# While deploying model to AKS PipelineModel.load throwing org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy model to AKS. I am using AML SDK to register the model in the aml workspace. I am using PipelineModel module to save the model. And I am trying to load the model using PipelineModel.load. My entry script looks like below:

` 
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

from azureml.core.model import Model
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel
from mmlspark import ComputeModelStatistics

def init():
    import mmlspark  # this is needed to load mmlspark libraries
    import logging

```
# extract and load model
global model, model_path
model_path = Model.get_model_path("{model_name}")
print(model_path)
print(os.stat(model_path))
print(os.path.exists(model_path))
#model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "{model_name}")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
#print(model_path)
#with ZipFile(model_path, 'r') as f:
#    f.extractall('model')
model = PipelineModel.load(model_path)
#model = PipelineModel.read().load(model_path)
```

def run(input_json):
    try:
        output_df = model.transform(pd.read_json(input_json))
        evaluator = ComputeModelStatistics().setScoredLabelsCol("prediction").setLabelCol("label").setEvaluationMetric("AUC")
        result = evaluator.transform(predictions)
        auc = result.select("AUC").collect()[0][0]
        result = auc
    except Exception as e:
        result = str(e)

```
return json.dumps({{"result": result}})
```

`

It's giving error like below:

org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/var/azureml-app/azureml-models/lightgbm.model/2/lightgbm.model/metadata\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315).

os.path.exists returns true the path fetched from Model.get_model_path.

Am I missing something here?